# How to use PHP's " .date('Y-m-d'). " in a MySQL query in Where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have cloned a movie theatre project where the `movie_carousel.php` uses a query to fetch movies from the MySQL database.

However it doesn't fetch any data when I run it, only when I remove the entire `Where` clause from the query - then it fetches the movies.

I believe it has something to do with the `.date('Y-m-d').` in the script.

What things I could try to fix it?

Here's the code of `movie_carousel.php`:

```
<?php 
  include 'admin/db_connect.php';
  $movies = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM movies where '".date('Y-m-d')."' BETWEEN date(date_showing) and date(end_date)" );
?>
```

Comment: isnt it `"SELECT * FROM movies where date('".date('Y-m-d')."') BETWEEN date(date_showing) and date(end_date)"`

Comment: Instead of inserting PHP into your query, you could use `DATE(NOW())` or `CURDATE()`.

Comment: Why do you use `date()` function in SQL?

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen That wouldn't make sense. It's already a date.

Comment: 1) Write SQL that works in your favourite MySQL client. 2) Extract the dynamic bits to separate parameters in a PHP prepared statement. 3) Populate parameters.

Comment: Please provide example of data from your table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use SQL rather than PHP when possible.

So you can replace :

```
$movies = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM movies where '".date('Y-m-d')."' BETWEEN date(date_showing) and date(end_date)" );
```

By:

```
$movies = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN DATE(date_showing) and DATE(end_date)" );
```

Also check if you really have datas in your table for now.

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/heYtYGoChmz28XeT7mzGsp/0#&togetherjs=bguyuSjnva

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem in the question, nor do you explain why it would.

Comment: "It is better" - Why should this be better?

Comment: @DarkBee It is better for numerous reasons, like for example security, performances, etc.

Comment: How does it affect security or performance?

Comment: I would say it is somewhat simpler and therefore easier to read. It reduces the chance of making mistakes with those quotes and format characters, errors which you might overlook.

Comment: I'm just asking this because the answer could be improved, just stating it is better is a long shot imho. @KIKOSoftware I could argue to just use a prepared statement then

Comment: For security, you're right, this case in not directly a concern. But check this case. 
In 2 month you have to update your application behaviour by changing today by an user choose date. Most of developpers will just add the user's date in the PHP date function. This can conduct to injection problems. 

About performance, do benchmark. It will reveal that using the PHP date function is longer than and more resource consuming than let the MySQL server doing the job. In other hand, if it is a busy server, why adding stuff to PHP applicaiotn server?

Comment: Just figured out that It had two issues 
 1- The one i just mentioned here
 2- The "end_date" column had data, all of which had expired .

Updating PHP function with SQL Date(Now()) And editing the "end_date" Column data solved it